# Invalid Pop Token error when tried to do a post call to rest api

Tags: python, api, post, pyspark

we have two APIs (One is an authorization API - where we get the access token and pop token from)
(another is the actual API where the resource is created)

I have been trying to hit the end API with the tokens generated by the auth API...When tried from my python script I get a 200 status code for the first, but a 401 Invalid pop token error for the end API.

Please help me find a solution to this.

Note- The APIs work well in the postman. I have been using the right headers and request body for both.

this is what i tried

```
tokens_response_json = tokens_response.json()
access_token = tokens_response_json['id_token']
pop_token = tokens_response_json['pop_token']
print("pop_token = ",pop_token)
headers = { Authorization = id_token,
            X-Authorization = pop_token}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data = mybody, verify = false)
#also tried 
response = HTTPsession.post(url, headers = headers, data = mybody, verify = false)
status_code = response.status_code
print("status Code : ",status_code)
```

Output:

```
Status_code : 400
Response : {"code" : "Security-1017", "userMessage" : "X-Authorization: Invalid PoP Token"}
```

(I printed the headers too)